# Am I assigning a reference to a function or a function in string form?

Tags: javascript

Assigning a function handler to a variable leads me to believe that my variable is now a reference to my function.  While this all seems fine and dandy, why can I concatenate a string with my "reference" and why is this concatenation reflected when I write my "reference" to the screen?

Why is my function reference being both handled and written as a string?

What is going on behind the scenes with references and type?

```js
var x = tester;

document.getElementById("test_button").onclick = x;

document.getElementById("test_p").innerHTML += (x + "<br>");
x += "Did I just concatenate a string?";
document.getElementById("test_p").innerHTML += (x);

function tester() {
  document.write("Hello World!");
}
```

```html
<button id="test_button">Press Me</button>
<br>
<p id="test_p"></p>
```

I assign the reference as an onclick for a button, and the function still executes as expected.

```
[Press Me] 
function tester() { document.write("Hello World!"); }
function tester() { document.write("Hello World!"); }Did I just concatenate 
a string?
```

Above is output, and when the button is pressed `"Hello World!"` is written to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can I concatenate a string with my "reference"

Because JavaScript performs type conversion when applying operators to values of data types that the operator does not support. The concatenation operator (`+`) is not defined for functions, so the function is converted to a string first.
The string representation of a user defined function is its source code.

> why is this concatenation reflected when I write my "reference" to the screen?

Because `x += y` (and `.innerHTML += y`) is the same as `x = x + y`. You are performing string concatenation and assign the new value (the string) back to `x` (`.innerHTML`). `x` used to hold a function, after that operation it holds a string.

> Why is my function reference being both handled and written as a string?

It's not. The value of `document.getElementById("test_button").onclick` does not change when you do `x += ...` (or `.innerHTML += ...`).

When you did

```
document.getElementById("test_button").onclick = x
```

you assigned a copy of the current value of `x` to `element.onclick`. At this point the value of `x` is a reference to a function.

When you do `x += ...` you assign a new value to `x`, but that doesn't change the value of the `onclick` property.

We start with

```
                        +---------------+
                        |               |
x: ref ---------------->|function tester|
                        |               |
                        +---------------+
```

After the assignment to `.onclick` we have

```
                                +---------------+
                                |               |
x: ref ------------------------>|function tester|
                                |               |
                                +---------------+
                                        ^        
                                        |        
element.onclick: ref  ------------------+
```

And after assigning the concatenated string to `x` we have

```
                                          +---------------+
                                          |               |
                                          |function tester|
                                          |               |
x: string "function tester()...."         +---------------+
                                                  ^        
                                                  |        
element.onclick: ref  ----------------------------+
```

> What is going on behind the scenes with references and type?

References don't really have anything to do with this here. Objects in JavaScript are [reference type values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c), but it's not like other languages where you can either access the reference or the referenced value. This all happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be stringified by calling `Function.toString()`. The type coercion from function to string happens automatically when you concatenate (the `+` operator with a string operand).

The MDN reference for [`Function.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) states:

> For user-defined [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) objects, the `toString` method returns a string containing the source text segment which was used to define the function.
>
> JavaScript calls the `toString` method automatically when a [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is to be represented as a text value, e.g. when a function is concatenated with a string.

In the case of setting an `.onclick` or `.innerHTML` property, the function object itself is assigned to the property. The difference is that `.innerHTML` ultimately stringifies the function by calling `fn.toString()` while `.onclick` invokes the function as a callback.

You can insert a `console.log` into the function's `toString` to validate that it truly was called when `innerHTML` was set or when you perform a concatenation:

```js
const foo = () => "hello";
foo.toString = () => console.log("toString called!") || "this is the toString() string";

42 + foo; // was toString really called?

const div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML = foo; // was toString really called?
```

... but not when `onclick` was set or invoked:

```js
const foo = () => console.log("hello");
foo.toString = () => console.log("toString called!") || "this is the toString() string";

const btn = document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.innerText = "click me to see if toString is called";
btn.onclick = foo;
```